# How to not break the makefile if patch skips the patch?

Tags: linux, makefile, patch

I want to apply a patch within a makefile. This works fine if the patch has not yet been applied. However, if I try to make after the original file has been patched already it causes the makefile to exit before finishing.

Makefile --

```
all:
        echo "starting patch"
        patch -N < patchfiles/foo.patch
        echo "patched"
```

Results after trying to run after file is already patched --

```
usr-mbp:makefile usr$ make
echo "starting patch"
starting patch
patch -N < patchfiles/foo.patch
patching file foo
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file foo.rej
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I figured using the -N option would simply skip the patch and not cause any errors. Apparently I was wrong. Any ideas on how to fix the makefile so it doesn't interpret the skipped patch as an error?

Thanks!

EDIT:

If I want to cd into a directory before the patch then using -patch does not work. This is the result:

Makefile:

```
all:
        echo "starting..."
        cd tmp && \
                -patch -N < ../patchfiles/Makefile.linux-p3041-3_0.patch
        echo "finished."
```

Results:

```
usr-mbp:makefile usr$ make
echo "starting..."
starting...
cd tmp && \
                -patch -N < ../patchfiles/Makefile.linux-p3041-3_0.patch
/bin/sh: line 1: -patch: command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a minus in front of a command [causes Make to ignore its exit status](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html).

```
-patch -N < patchfiles/foo.patch
```

You really must think this through, though; what if the command could also fail for reasons you do want to detect?  Maybe add a couple of sanity checks before or after the actual patch command.

Comment: thanks! yea good advice about the sanity checks. i'll definitely do that. thanks again! :)

Comment: Off the cuff, if `patch -R` on a copy of the file succeeds, you can skip the real thing.

Comment: made an edit. seems like -patch doesn't work if i want to cd into a directory before patching.

Comment: You need to put the minus first, in front of the `cd`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Can you explain what's special about `PKGBUILDs`?  This is a general Makefile facility so it should work for anything which uses a standard `Makefile`.

Comment: @tripleee never mind, I was searching the internet for how to make `patch` ignore a patched file, and didn't notice the question is specific to `Makefile`. FTR, PKGBUILD is rather bash script.

Answer (score 6):

I came across your question trying to do a similar thing but not with `make`.

I'm not a `make` person, but here is the logic you'd want to:

- Check if patch has been fully applied

  - Skip it if it is already applied
  - Apply it otherwise

-

```
# If we could reverse the patch, then it has already been applied; skip it
if patch --dry-run --reverse --force < patchfiles/foo.patch >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "Patch already applied - skipping."
else # patch not yet applied
  echo "Patching..."
  patch -Ns < patchfiles/foo.patch || echo "Patch failed" >&2 && exit 1
fi
```